# Vue js , How to target a data object if the name needs to be concatanated based on a variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am really struggling to find an answer for my use case, but I have been stuck for hours, and also unable to find a similar question in StackOverflow.
Here is a part of my code :

```
<v-tabs-items>
<v-tab-item
v-for="i in stepnumber"
:id="'tab-' + i"
:key="i"
>
<v-list two-line>
<div id="dropdown-example" class="minheight1">
<v-list-tile v-for="(item, index) in 'tabcomputed' + i" :key="item.id">
```

The `tabscomputed1`, `tabscomputed2`, etc. exist as data inside Vue, but I cannot find the proper syntax to target this data when I need to concat the `tabscomputed` with the variable `i` inside the `v-for` loop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you make `tabcomputed` as array in the component's `data`?

Comment: The tabscomputed1,2 etc are arrays of objects inside the component's data. 
I didn't do a general tabscomputed array because i want access to push different objects inside each of these individual arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `$data["tabscomputed"+i]`

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jw0q2x0k0) is a codesandbox link, check out **App.vue**

Comment: You Sir are a Genious ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Will it be easy to also share how to target these data arrays from inside a method? For example 
this.$data["tabscomputed"+i].push(something) doesn't work inside methods
how do a target these data from inside a method gicen that "i" is a variable passed to the method?

Comment: Try `this['tabscomputed'+i].push(something)` (I also upated the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jw0q2x0k0))

Comment: Perfect !
Thanks again.